# Conjugate numbers and Minkowski's inequality.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $u, v \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$, $p \in (1,\infty)$.

In a proof for Minkowski's inequality, it follows easily that $u + v \in \mathcal{L}^p$ and when trying to show the inequality, it goes $$\int |u+v|^p \ d\mu \le \int |u| \cdot |u+v|^{p-1} \ d \mu + \int |v| \cdot |u+v|^{p-1} \ d \mu$$
I understand that. Then it uses Holder's inequality, $$ \le \|u\|_p \cdot \| |u+v|^{p-1} \|_q + \|v\|_p \cdot \| |u+v|^{p-1} \|_q$$
How can it use Holder's inequality, which involves $q$, when the preceding argument has nothing to do with $q$ at all? How do we know that $|u + v |^{p-1} \in \mathcal{L}^q$?

Comment: Define $q$ to be such that $$ \frac1p + \frac 1q =1$$ i.e: $ \ p/q=p-1 \ \Longrightarrow \ q:=p/(p-1)$

Comment: I am new to this so I still don't understand... how does $\vert u + v \vert^{p-1} \in \boldsymbol{\mathcal{L}^q}$?